# How to differentiate between Google Bot visit and human

Tags: java

i just found a website display a title to google bot ,
and show another title when humnan visit the pages,
www.travelprofessor.com/
site it and visit the real page, you will find the difference.

Comment: *"you will find the difference."*  I think *you* will find a difference in SEO when Google discovers that you are trying to fool them.  To not get black-listed by Google, I would avoid such nonsense.

Comment: it is not my page...but i am in seo...

Comment: *"it is not my page"*  The best advice you can give the client is **Don't do it!** for the reason listed above.  Try and fool Google, and it will come back to bite you in the arse.

Comment: lol,sneaky and bit by snake..but i still wonder how the guy did it .do you know?

Answer (score 1):

Google "bots" use specific user-agents :

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en

As a side note, this is probably checked server-side, as the crawlers don't have Javascript...

Comment: Do you even have any idea what a user-agent is ?

Comment: i sometimes direct the carking spiders to google.lol...because they use many bandwith,and i do not need them ..

Comment: Congrats ! You're such a bad-ass !

Comment: lol,man, i am still confused how the guy did that...if you know ,please,Untie my doubts